# How to set default height for XRCrossBandBox & XRCrossBandLine in XtraReports Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, report

I need to set default height to XRCrossBandBox  & XRCrossBandLine  because, If I select one or two items in occupy less space in reports so that in bottom of page more space is available. To avoid that space I need to set Default height to XRCrossBandBox  & XRCrossBandLine.

I tried this code but its not working

```
private void DetailReport_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        xrCrossBandBox3.HeightF = 4 * (100 * 1);
        xrCrossBandLine6.HeightF = 4 * (100 * 1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the `EndPoint.Y` Property to resolve your problem. Instead of BeforePrint event you can use the Constructor of Report. But it should works on both ways.